# Function undefined when console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, undefined

why function Input() is undefined?
I am trying to create a second function to include to the onClick render but don't understand why it is not working.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

function input() {
  (disabled === disabled) ? setDisabled(!disabled) : '';
}
const handleClickEditMember = () => {
  Actions.enableMemberEdit();
  console.log(input(),'test');
};
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from the function. It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] ideally showing more of your react component.

Comment: add "return" expression before ternary operator will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This method does not return anything explicitly so by default it returns `undefined`

```
function input() {
  (disabled === disabled) ? setDisabled(!disabled) : '';
}
```

So when you log this to console

```
console.log(input(),'test');
```

It prints `undefined test`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are getting confused in normal functions and in Arrow functions,
In normal function if you want to return a value you have to return it using the return keyword.

```js
function input() {
  return (disabled === disabled) ? setDisabled(!disabled) : '';
}

console.log(input());

// In case of arrow Function
const input = () => (disabled === disabled) ? setDisabled(!disabled) : '';

console.log(input());

// disabled === disabled don't know what you are trying to acomplish here?
// if you want to toggle the disabled state then you should write 
// disabled ? setDisabled(false) : setDisabled(true)
```